# Can a contract require a contractor to not disclose their pay (in the USA)

Tags: salary, united-states, legal, contracting

My friend says that she's signed a contract that prohibits her from disclosing how much the contract is for. She's playing piano in a show, if that makes a difference. Is this legal? I know employees are legally protected if they share their salaries, but I imagine contractors might be a different game.

Edit: This is in North Carolina

Comment: You can put anything you want into a contract, enforcing it is another issue entirely. However you would at the very least have to specify a locale, and even then legal questions are not usually answered here.

Comment: Absolutely. non-disclosure is becoming increasingly common for more and more aspects of contractual work. You know when they report a lawsuit was settled out of court for an undisclosed amount? that's the result of a contract (aka formal agreement), if that's what the contract says.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer and this should not be taken as legal advice. You should consult with a lawyer.**

> My friend says that she's signed a contract that prohibits her from disclosing how much the contract is for... Is this legal?

Yes, because she is an [independent contractor and not an employee and thus not subject to the same federal protections that employee has](https://www.npr.org/2014/04/13/301989789/pay-secrecy-policies-at-work-often-illegal-and-misunderstood). Even if she signed an NDA, if she were an employee she would be protected and allowed to discuss her pay.